Как правильно поставить запятые в этом предложении с вводными словами?
Иван и по-видимому Пётр в этом не участвовали.

Здесь одно вводное слово - "по-видимому". Оно и обособляется запятыми:
Иван и, по-видимому, Пётр в этом не участвовали.
